# $p$-summable series in a Banach space

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

Let $E$ be a Banach space and denote its dual space by $E^*$. Let $p \in [1, \infty)$ and $x : \mathbb{N}\rightarrow E$ be such that for every $\phi \in E^*$,
$$\left( \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \lvert \phi(x(n))\rvert^p \right)^{1/p}$$
is finite. Why is
$$\sup_{\phi \in E^*, \lVert \phi \rVert \leq 1} \left( \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \lvert \phi(x(n))\rvert^p \right)^{1/p}$$
finite.

Answer (score 3):

This follows directly from the [Orlicz–Pettis theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orlicz%E2%80%93Pettis_theorem) (applied to the $p^{{\rm th}}$ power of your expression).

You can however avoid using this theorem by showing that the function

$$f(\phi) = \left( \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \lvert \phi(x(n))\rvert^p \right)^{1/p}\quad (\phi\in B_{E^*})$$

is continuous with respect to the weak*-topology. Then it will be bounded as $B_{X^*}$ is compact in the weak*-topology by the [Banach–Alaoglu theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banach%E2%80%93Alaoglu_theorem).